# Exponential distribution, how to apply in this task?

Tags: probability, statistics

We have a restaurant, where glasses brake every $6$ month with exponential distribution.

What is the probability, that

- From $5$ glasses, at most $3$ will break in $12$ month?
- From $500$ glasses, at most $300$ will break in $12$ month?

I understand the task, but I have no idea how to applay the definition of exponential distribution. We have $\lambda = 1/6$ month? What is $X$?
Any help or hint appreciated. Or we have $E(X) = 1/6$ if $X=1$?

Answer (score 1):

If $X_i$ is the lifespan in years of glass $i$ then $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. Exp$(2)$, since $E(X_i)=1/2$ (i.e. $6$ months).

Then the number, $Y$, of breakages from $n$ glasses in $1$ year has a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution where $p=P(X_i\leq 1)=F(1)=1-e^{-2}$.

The two probabilities required can then be calculated by standard binomial formulae, or perhaps by Normal approximation to the Binomial.

Comment: For the second task, could I use De Moivre-Laplace Theorem?

Comment: @Atvin Yes, it passes the tests contained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation